# How many nodes I can deploy on a single machine in Corda?

Tags: corda

I am working on distributed ledger system on 16 GB machine. I want to know how many nodes I can deploy so that all nodes works fine. 
Is it hardware depended?

Comment: Hi - it's going to depend on how chatty they are, how much stuff they are doing outside the Corda framework and also number of cores, processor speed etc.

Answer (score 0):

For testing I suggested assign at least 500M for JVM heap, of course heap is not everything what Java application needs. There is also OS and other application, so probably you should be able to fit between 10 and 16 nodes, maybe a bit more. However, if your application is big, you might need to lower above number.

You didn't mentioned number of cores.

If you plan production please speak with R3.